# Swift 2.2 and 2.3 interoperability

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

My project is in Objective C, with some piece of code in Swift 2.3

Can I add/use a private third party framework in Objective C with some piece of code in Swift 2.2 ?

What about when I will migrate to Swift 3 ?

Thanke

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:**

I would like to share my some experiences with you.

1. What version of Xcode you are using. In Xcode 8 Swift version lower than 2.3 is not supported.
2. If you are still using Xcode 7 then there might not be an issue of fix swift version of 2.2 and 2.3 as both comes under swift legacy versions. If you want to user third party framework using cocoa pods then you also need to set Use Legacy Swift Language version to YES.

Comment: I use Xcode 8.2.1 and swift 2.3

Comment: Xcode 8 comes with two swift versions one is 2.3 and another is 3.0. So you should not be able to use that but I found this link http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/ that shows some work around so that you can also use 2.2 with Xcode 8. But i strongly recommend you to switch to Swift 3. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes this is help me, thanks : I'm going to force third party company to provide me a framework with swift 3.0. I think it is not good to integrate today a framework with swift 2.2... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the up vote @lafalex

Answer (score 1):

No - you need to be on the same version of Swift in your entire project.

See https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md